# How to pass .env file in npm run build?

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, environment-variables

React app: I have my settings working in Node.js development (I'm passing an .env file through Docker), however they don't in Nginx production.

Do I need to know something about passing environment variables to files in npm run build?

Here's my Dockerfile with env variables coming from .env located in dir of and read by `docker-compose`.

The container in question is `sprintbotmanager`.

Dockerfile

```
# Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js to build the frontend
FROM node:alpine as build
MAINTAINER Kuba Wasilewski <jakub.wasilewski@sprint.pl>
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN apk add --update python make g++\
   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN npm install
ARG REACT_APP_API_URL
ENV REACT_APP_API_URL ${REACT_APP_API_URL}
COPY . /app/
RUN npm run build

# Stage 1, "run-phase", based on NGINX to provide SSL configuration and serve static files
FROM nginx:alpine
MAINTAINER Kuba Wasilewski <jakub.wasilewski@sprint.pl>
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ARG REACT_APP_API_URL
ENV REACT_APP_API_URL ${REACT_APP_API_URL}
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY nginx/server.cert /etc/nginx
COPY nginx/server.key /etc/nginx
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  sprintbotserver:
    container_name: sprintbotserver
    restart: always
    image: sprintbotserver:latest
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./logs:/sprintbotserver/logs"
      - "./chatbots:/sprintbotserver/chatbots"
      - "./config:/sprintbotserver/config"
      - "./db:/sprintbotserver/db"
      - "./demo:/sprintbotserver/demo"
      - "./dic:/sprintbotserver/dic"
      - "./lib:/sprintbotserver/lib"
      - "./models:/sprintbotserver/models"
      - "./audit:/sprintbotserver/audit"
      - "./tmp:/sprintbotserver/tmp"
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
      "sprint.bot.frontend.host": "$CLIENT_URL",
      "sprint.bot.localDbRemoveTime.cron": "$LOCAL_DB_REMOVE_CRON"
    }'
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"

  sprintbotmanager:
    container_name: sprintbotmanager
    restart: always
    image: sprintbotmanager:latest
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "/node_modules"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - sprintbotserver
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - REACT_APP_API_URL=${SERVER_URL}
      - REACT_APP_RECORDING_API_URL=${RECORDING_SERVER_URL}
    stdin_open: true
```

.env

```
# === Docker-compose configuration ===

#API Server URL
SERVER_URL=https://192.168.254.159:8443

#Recording API Server URL
RECORDING_SERVER_URL=https://192.168.254.159:8444

#Manager Server URL
CLIENT_URL=https://192.168.254.159
```

Comment: Check this out https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-pass-environment-variables/. I personally use option 2.

Comment: That's exactly what I have right now and it doesn't work... :(

Comment: Than you should provide more info about your setup =)

Comment: @KonstantinSamarin added my Docker config, please help me :)

Comment: To be clear: I meant npm build, not docker build.

Comment: I believe that for the project node required a diferent `.env`. The environemnts sets on docker-compose is only  provider for docker.

Comment: No, it works with node just fine. The problem is Nginx...

Comment: Hm... And how do you reference the ENV in nginx?

Comment: Well, have to say that the question, if not analyzed word by word, it is not so understandable. By the way, at the end, the problem seems to be clear. I don't think I have enough characters to explain the problem in dept so my suggestion is to update the question. So please, make the question more clear and explain in depth your issue.

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli At the moment of asking the question I thought it would be possible to dynamically pass some env variables to the static web content served by nginx... silly me :)

Comment: Well, just a few question that may help: when you say "Dockerfile with env variables", you mean that you are sure that the "${REACT_APP_API_URL}" actually have a value? I'm asking because in the question seems that you are sure that the value is in place. How do you pass the ARG to your `Dokerfile`?

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli Yes I'm sure the value's in place, it's been working like so in node.js development Dockerfile for months...

Comment: @k-wasilewski I am pretty match sure that I found the problem but to give the answer I would consider too many things as an assumption with the risk to write the wrong answer! Also this comment section is too limited to discuss :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228642/discussion-between-emanuele-scarabattoli-and-k-wasilewski).